# Let $G$ be a group. Prove or disprove that $H=\{g^2~ |~g\in G\}$ is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Prove or disprove that $H = \{ g^{2} \mid g \in G \}$ is a subgroup of $G$.

From other places on the interwebs, I have found that I should be able to use the Alternating Group $A_{4}$ to disprove $H$, but I don't know how to use $A_{4}$ to do that.

**Edit**
I am not sure how to square elements of $A_{4}$, so I'm looking at the Cayley Table for $A_{4}$.  If I am reading this table correctly, then (1)<sup>2</sup>=(1), [(12)(34)]<sup>2</sup> = (1) , [(13)(24)]<sup>2</sup> = (1), [(14)(23)]<sup>2</sup> = (1), (123)<sup>2</sup> = (132) ... 
 Assuming I am reading the table correctly, then does the fact that (123)<sup>2</sup> = (132) disprove H={g<sup>2</sup> |g∈G}?

http://faculty.capebretonu.ca/jpreen/a4table.png[image]

Comment: Hint: 1) List the elements of $A_4$ (there are only 12). 2) Compute their squares. 3) Check whether the resulting set is a subgroup. A checkpoint along the way: You should get a lot of permutations of order three and not much else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative way of looking at it is to notice that all $3$-cycles in $A_{4}$ are squares, as $(i j k) = (i k j)^{2}$, where $i,j,k$ are different. As the square of any element of the form $(i j) (k l)$ (with $i, j, k, l$ distinct) is $1$, the set of squares consists of $1$, and all $3$-cycles.

But there are
$$
\frac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2}{3} = 8
$$
$3$-cycles, so all in all $1 + 8 = 9$ squares, This cannot be a subgroup, as $9$ does not divide the order of $A_{4}$, which is $12$.

Answer (score 5):

To prove the statement is false, you only have to find a group $G$ with two squares $a^2,b^2 \in G$ such that $a^2b^2$ is not itself a square.

One solution is to look at $A_4$, as suggested by Jyrki Lahtonen. Another is to look at the free group $\mathbb{F}_2= \langle a,b \mid \ \rangle$, and to prove that $a^2b^2$ is not a square. It can be proved combinatorially, or you can just notice that the quotient $\mathbb{F}_2 / \langle \langle a^2b^2 \rangle \rangle$ is torsion-free.

Comment: Does the following work:  If a=(123), then a^2=(132), If b=(143), then b^2=(134).  a^2*b^2 = (12)(34), which is not the solution to the square of any element in G? Also, can't use Free Groups as my class hasn't gotten that far yet.

Comment: Yes, it works. You can notice that $(12)(34)$ is not a square from the Cayley table you wrote or solving the equation $(12)(34)= \sigma^2$: decomposing $\sigma$ into disjoint cycles, notice that $\sigma$ must be the product of two permutations, which implies $\sigma^2=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: It is unfortunate that I can only select one answer as a solution because the combination of answers from Jyrki, Seirios, and @Andreas helped to solidify this concept in my mind.